# Logstash Load Error

Tags: java, linux, windows, logstash, elastic-stack

When I try to run logstash, I get a load error: JRuby ext built for wrong Java version. Does anyone know what this means and how I can resolve it. I`m running this on putty if it makes a difference.

[Command Line Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10OhJ.png)

Comment: what is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: @WillBarnwell 1.7.0_99

Comment: how did you install logstash?

Comment: also putty is an ssh client, so what are you ssh'ing to?

Comment: Doing this for a company so two of us are working on it. Not sure, I'm currently reinstalling logstash to make sure the error isn't there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I had this error on a Windows box, and I solved it by updating Java.

In my case, I updated it from an earlier version of Java 8 to Java version "1.8.0_121".